# php-Limiting dropdown option based on another dropdown where option isn't predetermined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I'm trying to make an invoice php page which contain 2 dropdown option: Supplier_Name and Item_ID. Both of them is not predetermined. Supplier_Name option obtained from another page (List of Supplier, which can be modify). Item_ID option obtained from another page too (List of Item, which can be modify too). I'm quite new about this and my data is small, so I'm looking the simplest way possible.

So far, I knew how to populate Supplier_Name from List of Supplier database. I used this code:

```
<td>Supplier</td>   
    <td>
    <?php  
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
        mysql_select_db("stock");  
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from input_supplier_data");  
        $jsArray = "var invoice = new Array();\n";  
        echo '<select name="supplier_name" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">';  
        echo '<option></option>';  
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
        echo '<option value="' . $row['supplier_name'] . '">' . $row['supplier_name'] . '</option>';  
        $jsArray .= "invoice['" . $row['supplier'] . "'] = {name:'" . addslashes($row['supplier']) . "',desc:'".addslashes($row[''])."'};\n";  
            } 
        echo '</select>';  
    ?>  
    </td>

    <br /<input type="text" name="input_supplier_data" id="input_supplier_data"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        <?php echo $jsArray; ?>
        function changeValue(id){
        document.getElementById('input_supplier_data').value = supplier_name[id].name;
    };
    </script>
```

When a Supplier selected, only their product will be displayed in the second dropdown option. Since List of Item page contain all item from all supplier, I don't know how to limit them. What I can do so far is only if the supplier was predetermined. I used this code:

```
SELECT input_item_data.`item_id` FROM `input_item_data` WHERE input_item_data.`supplier` = 'UNILEVER'
```

But as I stated earlier, the item is not predetermined, it can be modify in List of Item page. Hope anyone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: You can use javascript to listen for the change in the first dropdown, then do an ajax call to a php script with the value from drop down 1 to fetch the correct alternatives for drop down 2. And then insert them in the drop down field.

Comment: Is there any other way without using ajax? I don't know anything about it :(

Comment: If you are coding, then I would strongly recommend not to avoid any procedure/technique just because you don't know anything. Honestly speaking, it might take not more than 4 to 5 hours for you to understand AJAX and use it efficiently.